# Apply Gradient to an Outline

Tags: css

How do I apply a gradient to an outline?

From my understanding it is possible to do this with borders through border-image, however, I have not found the implementation of a gradient to an outline.

Is it possible?

Gradient Example

```
linear-gradient(179.98deg, rgba(104, 213, 255, 1) 0.12%, rgba(45, 179, 222, 1) 14.53%, #467EE3 99.88%);
```

Edit:

I have an existing border (1px #000 solid), so border-image will not work.

Edit #2:

jsfiddle example of current https://jsfiddle.net/b4x0fame/

While maintaining the black border, I would like the outline to be a gradient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of border-image. You can check it out and use the same technique in your code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaspas/Mk9EN/)

```
<div class='bordered'>1</div>

div {
height: 100px; width: 100px;
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px auto;
background-clip: padding-box;
}
.bordered {
border: 20px double pink;
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,orange,yellow) 20 stretch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `border-image` to your gradient. In this case, something like:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-image: linear-gradient(179.98deg, rgba(104, 213, 255, 1) 0.12%, rgba(45, 179, 222, 1) 14.53%, #467EE3 99.88%);
```

https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: I should have clarified, I already have a border (1px #000 solid).

Comment: Updated. You could probably also just add the gradient instead of the #000, but that's untested.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top-to-bottom { border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%; -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%; -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%; -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%; border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="top-to-bottom"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
```